# Setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore, environment-variables

I am working on a Go project. I want to create an .env file. I refer to the docs but I am not understanding how to do it & where to put that file & how can I use it? Can you guys please help me?
Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#go

Comment: Go doesn't have any built-in support for `.env` files. If you want to use such a file, you'll need to install a third-party library to support it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a `.env` file in Golang, you can use the `github.com/joho/godotenv` module. Then, you can load your file with `godotenv.Load()`.

I usually prefer to use `direnv` and have `.envrc` for each of my project so I can just the `os` lib and load the environment variables :)

Comment: In .env file I have to give fire store key but I am not understanding hoew to give. I referred docs but not understood. Can you please help me?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#go_5

Comment: @rakshit I suppose this followup qustion of yours is worth posting a separate question in stack to be answered.